# Javascript: Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, token

I'm using CodeAcademy, and I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game. It keeps saying I have a syntax error due to an "Unexpected token else". Take a look at my code:

```
var compare = function(choice1,choice2){

if(choice1===choice2){

return "The result is a tie!";

}

else if(choice1==="rock") {

if(choice2==="scissors") {
        return "rock wins!";
    }
    else {
        return ("paper wins!");

} else if(choice1==="paper"){
    if(choice2 ==="rock") {
        return"paper wins!";
    }
    else {
        return"scissors wins!";

  }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an if block which looks like this:

```
       if (choice2 === "scissors") {
          ...
       } else {
          ...
       } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
          ...
       }
```

`else if` can only come before an `else`, not after.

Using consistent indentation will make this sort of problem clearer, here is the code after running it through the formatter at http://jsbeautifier.org/

```
   var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
       if (choice1 === choice2) {
           return "The result is a tie!";
       } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
           if (choice2 === "scissors") {
               return "rock wins!";
           } else {
               return ("paper wins!");
           } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
               if (choice2 === "rock") {
                   return "paper wins!";
               } else {
                   return "scissors wins!";
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Here it is again, formatted so that the `choice1 ===` lines are all at the function level, which seems to make it easier to see the structure and reduces nesting.

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }

    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins!";
        } else {
            return "paper wins!";
        }
    }

    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins!";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: might be worth noting that even the corrected syntax is still not a valid solution for the rock-paper-scissors game.. otherwise very nice answer :)

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how much more to add. What happens when `choice1` is `scissors`? The answer stands out a bit more with this formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You used a parentheses with return statement at `return ("paper wins!");`. Please remove the `()`.

Also,you have a wrong number of parentheses aligned before first else-if and second else-if.

Please close first else-if with a curly-bracket`}` and delete one excess from the bottom. That's the main cause of error!

Comment: @user3258980-Also don't forget to accept one of the answers after your problem gets solved. Please reply whether your problem got solved or not!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have wrong number of curly parentheses.